# Direct Comparison Behavior in Generics

Tags: c#, generics

I've been reading [C# in Depth, Third Edition](http://www.manning.com/skeet3/) and it is talking about some weird behaviors of Generics that I was not aware of before: `==` and `!=` comparisons in Generics. Let's look at the example below: (Note: you can run the following codes directly on [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/))

```
static bool AreEqual<T>(T first, T second)
{
    return first == second;
}
```

You can use this method as it is. When you execute the following code, the compiler will complain and say "**Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'"**

```
void Main()
{
    int first = 1;
    int second = 1;
    (first == second).Dump("Normal Comparison");
    AreEqual(first, second).Dump("Generic Comparison");
}
```

If there is no type constraint applied, you are only allowed to compare with `null` as following:

```
static bool AreEqual<T>(T value)
{
    return value == null;
}
```

However, when you apply Reference Type Constraint like following, then `Main()` method will work:

```
static bool AreEqual<T>(T first, T second) where T:class
{
    return first == second;
}
```

but if the it is Value Type Constraint, then the following code won't work:

```
void Main()
{
    int first = 1;
    int second = 1;
    (first == second).Dump("Normal Comparison");
    AreEqual(first, second).Dump("Generic Comparison");
}

static bool AreEqual<T>(T first, T second) where T:struct
{
    return first == second;
}
```

I think Jon Skeet is trying to explain it in the following pages. He is saying:

> Basically, when `AreReferencesEqual<T>` is compiled, the compiler
>   doesn't know what overloads will be available -- it's as if the
>   paramaters passed in were of type `object`.

The quote above might be the answer but I am still confused as for why it is behaving like this. By the way, `AreReferencesEqual<T>` method is the same thing with my method with the signature `static bool AreEqual<T>(T first, T second) where T:class`. My question is why we are seeing this strange behavior.

Comment: You know that you haven't asked a question?

Comment: @Enigmativity :) Sorry, I added my question. But I thought people could have inferred my question from the last paragraph when I said I was confused.